# unreachable function from class

Tags: c++

Why I cant see function in class? Gives me error producent() is not in this scope

```
class A
{
    public:
    void method()
    {
        pthread_t p;
        pthread_create(&p, NULL, producent, NULL);
    }
};

void * producent ( void )
 {
   return ( NULL );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the method before its usage.

```
void * producent ( void );
class A
{
    public:
    void method()
    {
        pthread_t p;
        pthread_create(&p, NULL, producent, NULL);
    }
};

void * producent ( void )
{
   return ( NULL );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't know it. Add the prototype above the class:

```
   void *producer(void);
```